# PHP increasing the post method's limit

Tags: php, xampp

I'm trying to do a PHP program to transfer an excel file to a selected table in database while working on XAMPP on my local machine. After reading the Excel file successfully in a PHP file with PHP-Excel, I stored it in an array I serialize it and send it to another PHP file with a hidden input.

This is the part I read the file into an array and serialize

```
$arr = array();
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row);
        array_push($arr, $rowData);
    }
$dataStr = serialize(arr);
```

And this is the part I send it

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'hidden' value = <?php echo $dataStr;?>>
```

With the code below I get it the array in other PHP file

```
$arr = unserialize($_POST['hidden']);
```

This code works perfect with small tables but when I tried to work with a big excel file (which makes the $dataStr variable a 26000 characters string) The second PHP file can only read less than 50 characters. Even after increasing the post-max-size to 32M, the problem still continues. My PHP version is 5.5.11.

So can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: sorry forgot to add the PHP version to my question, it's 5.5.11

Comment: You'll have to specify MAX_INPUT_VARS in your php.ini

Comment: Might the problem be `post_max_size`?http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: changed max_input_vars to 50000 and max_input_time to -1 (unlimited) but it still doesnt work

Comment: @eithedog "Even after increasing the post-max-size to 32M, the problem still continues" already tried

Comment: Try to write on a temp file and just pass the temp name to read it

Comment: @BrokenFrog Keep in mind, whenever you change anything in `php.ini`; you have to restart `apache` before it takes effect. I'd recommend always reading `phpinfo()` after you make changes, to ensure they actually took effect.

Comment: @Killrawr I know and restarted the server everytime I did the changes.

Comment: @KA_lin nice approach will try it now but i still wonder what caused the problem

Comment: @BrokenFrog - where are you changing this value? It might be that your config settings disallow you from using ini_set (or you're editing wrong config file - sorry, but I've got to mention that ;)) - best is to edit .htaccess. The other thing is that when sending the data through POST the values will become url encoded, so the values that you're sending might grow 5-6 times

Comment: @eithedog since i'm working on a local machine there is no htaccess file i change the values in XAMPP's php.ini which is in ..\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: @BrokenFrog - you still can use .htaccess (but let's not get into that here). You're not hitting browser POST limit nor server POST limit - and the setting of `post_max_size` should solve the issue. Unfortunately phpfiddle is not working atm, so can't really help beyond what I've already written. One more thing - can you try putting in your php code `ini_set('post_max_size', '64M'); var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size')); ` at the top?

Comment: @eithedog the file that sends the post or both of the files?

Comment: @BrokenFrog the file that sends, please

Comment: still unsolved but in the start of the page `string(3) "32M"` is written now

Comment: @BrokenFrog - This means that indeed you cannot change config.ini settings from within the php file, but you're updating the correct file and limit should be enough for the data you're sending. Really bizarre.

Comment: @eithedog am i wrong or shouldn't php read it as an int of 32.000.000 value? So is the problem in my php compiler which reads the 32M as a string?

Comment: @BrokenFrog - No, the value that's displaying is correct - 32 megabytes. `PHP allows shortcuts for bit values, including K (kilo), M (mega) and G (giga). PHP will do the conversions automatically if you use any of these`

Comment: @eithedog i see thank you, so it is still unsolved i'll try to do it with KA_lin's approach. Writing the serialized post to a file and reading from it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xampp then go to php folder in xampp folder.
There open the php.ini-development file.
Find the below line

```
post_max_size = 8M
```

Here you can Increase the Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
I did the same when I faced the same problem.

Comment: sorry but I stated in the question I already did that "Even after increasing the post-max-size to 32M, the problem still continues" so it's not working for me